# How do I provide a list of custom autocomplete suggestions for the input field, in ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic3

Very similar to the location input fields when completing twitter's user profiles. And so when the user types in the first letter in the field it provides a list of regions and their respective countries that start with the letter that the user has put, of course using ionic 3 framework.

Comment: you mean like a search feature?

Comment: Kind of, but it is in a form. And gets submitted with the rest of the input data in that form, on a click of a button.

Comment: Well can you change that and include ion-searchbar ?

Comment: what I mean is "how do I provide a list of custom autocomplete suggestions for the input field. in a form"